# Cleanup function in C

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have a C program which allocates a few buffers which need to be cleared before the program exits execution. My `main` program looks like this

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    // Some code
    // ...
    // ...
    void* data1 = malloc(someSize);
    void* data2 = malloc(someSize);
    double* result = malloc(resultSize);
    double* buffer = malloc(buffSize);
    // Some code
    // ...
    // First exit point
    if(someExitcondition){
        // free all allocated memory
        exit(1);
    }
    // Some code
    // ...
    // Second exit point
    if(someOtherExitcondition){
        // free all allocated memory
        exit(1);
    }
    // Some code
    // ...

    // free all allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

I want to make cleaning up easier by just invoking a `cleanUp()` function which will `free` all the memory allocated in the heap. I want to call this function right before every `exit(1)` call and before the `return 0` line (Essentially replace every comment `// free all allocated memory` with a call to `cleanUp()`). **My question is that how do I pass the pointers `data1`,`data2`,`result` and `buffer` to `cleanUp()` such that they can be freed?**

This is what I am thinking to do. Is this the right approach?

```c
void cleanUp(void* p1, void* p2, void* p3, void* p4){
    // call to free for each pointer
}
```

Comment: I assume cleanUp is only going to be called once, right before you exit?

Comment: Yea I want to call it once to clean up all allocated memory right before the program exits but there might multiple exit points in the program

Comment: Oh, I see.  So how come your cleanUp method doesn't have the same declarations?

Comment: `public void cleanUp(void* data1, 
    void* data2, 
    double* result, 
    double* buffer)`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I might have more pointers to free as my program grows thats why I define them as `p1`, `p2` etc

Comment: `a few buffers which need to be cleared before the program exits` In fact, that's not necessary, as all process memory is freed upon exit anyway.

Comment: @Matt I don't believe that is necessarily true, but it is an assumption that will hold true for most OSes.

Comment: @sudo97: I don't recommend that.  Make your cleanup function match exactly the things you've allocated.

Comment: Put all of your allocated buffers in a single struct; Then you can create a cleanup() method that takes a pointer to the struct instance as its argument, and free all of the buffers in that method. You can call that method from anywhere that the struct instance is in scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've ever been taught to never use `goto`, well something like is a prime example of a good time to use `goto`.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int ret_status = 0;
    // Some code
    // ...
    // ...
    void* data1 = malloc(someSize);
    void* data2 = malloc(someSize);
    double* result = malloc(resultSize);
    double* buffer = malloc(buffSize);
    // allocation failure: first exit point
    if(!(data1 && data2 && result && buffer)){
        ret_status = 1;
        goto cleanup;
    }
    // Some code
    // ...
    // Second exit point
    if(someOtherExitcondition){
        ret_status = 1;
        goto cleanup;
    }
    // Some code
    // ...

cleanup:
    // free all allocated memory     
    free(data1);
    free(data2);
    free(result);
    free(buffer);

    return ret_status;
}
```

If, unlike the given example, you were also calling `exit()` from nested functions, look at using `atexit()` as given in Jonathan Leffler's answer.

Comment: This is the approach I recommend.

Comment: Remember to handle allocation errors. `if (data1 == NULL || data2 == NULL || result == NULL || buffer == NULL) goto cleanup;`

Comment: This is not a prime example for `goto`, and it does not achieve the question’s request of performing cleanup with every `exit` call, since an `exit` outside of `main` will bypass these. The C standard provides a facility for this, the `atexit` call, which registers a function to be called when the program is exiting.

Comment: @KamilCuk I was deciding whether or not I wanted to increase the complexity of the example by handling the allocation errors.  I guess since all of the allocation is done together here, we can do something like that and keep it simple.  I'll commandeer one of the hypothetical conditionals for the example to handle bad allocation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That depends on your interpretation of the question.  With the example given by the OP, this would be the simplest way to do it.  If we were to expect the program to exit from different functions, that is when I would start looking at using `atexit`, which requires extra work to make sure the function has access to the identifiers that need to be freed.  In my view, both methodologies warrant existing as reference for this question so that future users can see cleanup methods that work in scenarios of exiting functions and exiting programs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have updated the answer to also mention `atexit` for scenarios in which the program exits from a nested function, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

More or less, but maybe a better approach is to register a callback with [`atexit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atexit.html).  That will be called whenever the program exits normally (via `exit()`, or on return from `main()` to the startup code).  The downside is that the signature of the cleanup function is `void cleanup(void)` — no arguments.  That means that the function must have access to global (or file scope) variables.  But it gives the maximum reliability for getting the cleanup executed.

There's also the argument that if your program is about to exit, it doesn't matter whether you call `free()` or not — the system will release the memory anyway.  However, programs like [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) will complain about lost memory if you don't free it — it is often good practice to free it even so.

Comment: What if I move my pointer declarations `data1`, `data2`, `result` and `buffer` outside the `main` function?

Comment: That's what you'd need to do for a separate cleanup function to be able to access them.  You'd make them `static` so they don't pollute the global symbol space (no other files should be accessing them), but your cleanup function can do its work with them.  They're even default initialized to NULL (zero) so it is safe to pass them to `free()` even if not yet allocated.  Note that the cleanup function will be called even if the exit is in a function deep down the calling hierarchy (in a function called from `main()`, or one of the functions those call, ad nauseam).

Comment: It may be cleaner to create a single static object for the use of the exit-handler function—a structure or linked list or something in which memory to be freed (and/or other tasks to be performed) is listed. Then there is just “one thing” whose purpose is more easily made clear than a scattering of static pointers, even if the thing is just a structure with members that are the pointers.

Comment: Yes, @EricPostpischil — I have used such systems in code where I needed to release data allocated between a `setjmp()` and the matching `longjmp()`, too.

Comment: Because of the extra work involved in making the identifiers available to `atexit()`, I think an example of how to set it up would be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the *non standard* `cleanup` feature supported by `gcc` and `clang`, which simplifies the code, and and makes your code more secure.

```
void free_void(void **value)     { free(*value); }
void free_double(double **value) { free(*value); }

int main()
{
    /* Return any time you like and allocated things get freed */

    __attribute__((cleanup(free_void))) void *data1 = malloc(someSize);
    __attribute__((cleanup(free_void))) void *data2 = malloc(someSize);
    __attribute__((cleanup(free_double))) double *result = malloc(resultSize);
    __attribute__((cleanup(free_double))) double *buffer = malloc(buffSize);

    return 0;
}
```

You could simplify this with macros:

```
static inline void free_void(void **value)     { free(*value); }
#define cleanup__void_ptr __attribute__((cleanup(free_void))) void *

static inline void free_double(double **value) { free(*value); }
#define cleanup__double_ptr __attribute__((cleanup(free_double))) double *

int main()
{
    /* Return any time you like and allocated things get freed */

    cleanup__void_ptr data1 = malloc(someSize);
    cleanup__void_ptr data2 = malloc(someSize);
    if(!data2) {
        return 0;
        /* calls `free()` on data1 and data2. */
    }
    cleanup__double_ptr result = malloc(resultSize);
    cleanup__double_ptr buffer = malloc(buffSize);

    return 0;
    /* calls `free()` on data1, data2, result and buffer */
}
```

Instead of using `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` I would highly recommend, to attach a cleanup function to any allocated resources, so that you can have a `return` statement anywhere. Any caller of a function then should check the return value. If an error is indicated return immediately, or handle the exception. This way you do not need `setjmp()`/`longjmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

The hacky answer: don't.

Let me qualify that!

Don't free the memory ONLY if indeed this your main() function.

What I mean is that after main exits the process memory is going to be freed anyways so why bother?

If on the other hand your function is not main and you have to free-up the memory to avoid running out of memory then you need one of the other answers. My preferred order:

- call cleanup()* before any exit function
- **attribute**((cleanup(free_void))) - this is rather neat but may not work in all cases (think older compilers, etc.)
- goto

Hope this added a bit of color to the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call

```c
    cleanUp(data1, data2, result, buffer);
```

as those variables have as values the pointers that have been allocated and that is what you would pass to `free()` anyway.

I think that a better approach would be to use a `goto` statement to the cleanup section at the end of your function. This is one of the few cases where the `goto` is more useful than harmful. Imagine how would your code look if you would have 50 functions which use this kind of buffers and all of them should have their own corresponding cleanup function.

Check on Christian Gibbons's answer.